# How can I change the default x & y coordinates of a cells text label

Tags: swift

in my story board i have the text label of my custom in the middle of the cell. When my cells are being created the number of rows generated are based off of my dictionaries "foodAndTemp.count" the cells textLabel is being generated by the keys in the dictionary here is a little snippet of code for what im doing so far to catch you up.

```
@IBOutlet weak var foodCellItemLabel: UILabel!


  let foodNameAndDangerLevel: [String : Int] = ["Chocolate Cake":400, "Apple Pie":350]

  let keys = [String](foodAndTemp.keys)
  let (food, temp) = (keys[indexPath.row], foodAndTemp[keys[indexPath.row]])

  var foodLabel:String = food  
  var foodTitle = foodCellItemLabel

  foodTitle.text! = foodLabel

  var foodTitleName = foodTitle!.text

  cell.textLabel!.text = foodTitleName
```

now, I know what my problem is, I'm setting the value of the cells textLabel.**text** but not setting anything for just the **textLabel** . So, Anyone think they know how to do this and can help me, and no  don't want to add a few spaces before the title so it puts the text in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the alignment on the UILabel to centered in IB.

Comment: are you talking about in the story board? if so the alignment is set to the middle already